# Page postback - double binding

Tags: button, data-binding, datagrid, postback, modal-dialog

I've got a webpage that has a datagrid that's built dynamically depending on the date and filters selected.  On itemdatabound a linkbutton is created for each cell so when clicked will open a modal popup with the details that can be amended. The problem I've got is that when I change the filters (datepicker, btnShow) the page is binding twice and duplicating the columns in the grid.  If I put a != page.ispostback, when I click a cell linkbutton, the datagrid disappears.
Please help

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="Frm.aspx.cs" Inherits="web.Frm" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="Scripts/script.js"> </script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.8.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#<%= datepicker.ClientID %>').datepicker({ changeMonth: true, changeYear: true });
        });

    </script>

    <asp:ScriptManager runat="server" ID="scriptManager" EnablePageMethods="true">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:Button ID="btnShowPopupAmend" Style="display: none" runat="server" />
    <!--Start:Amend Details-->
    <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpeAmend" runat="server" TargetControlID="btnShowPopupAmend"
        PopupControlID="pnlpopupAmend" CancelControlID="imgCancel" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" />
    <asp:Panel ID="pnlpopupAmend" runat="server" Width="700px" Style="display: none;"
        class="ModalPanel">
        <asp:Panel ID="pnlInner" runat="server" BackColor="white" Width="700px">
            <table style="width: 700px;" class="BG">
                <tr>
                    <td width="10px">
                        &nbsp;
                    </td>
                    <td align="left">
                        <asp:Label ID="lbl" runat="server" Text="Amend" CssClass="norm_w" Font-Bold="True"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td align="right">
                        <asp:Button ID="btnAmendCloseConfirm" runat="server" Text="x" OnClick="imgCancel_Click">
                        </asp:Button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </tr>
                <table style="width: 700px;">
                    <tr height="25">
                        <td width="10px">
                            &nbsp;
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" CssClass="norm">&nbsp;Name:</asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="LblName" runat="server" CssClass="norm"></asp:Label>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr height="25">
                        <td width="10px">
                            &nbsp;
                        </td>
                        <td valign="top">
                            <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" CssClass="norm">&nbsp;Address:</asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TxtAddress" runat="server" CssClass="norm_no_border" TextMode="MultiLine"
                                Rows="4" Width="300px" Style="overflow: hidden"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <br />
                <asp:Button ID="imgCancel" Text="cancel" Height="25px" Width="80px" runat="server"
                    OnClick="imgCancel_Click" />
        </asp:Panel>
    </asp:Panel>
    <!--End:Amend Details-->
    <!--Start:Filters-->
    <div>
        <asp:Label ID="Lbl1" runat="server" CssClass="norm">Show Details:</asp:Label>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="ChkDetails" runat="server"></asp:CheckBox>
        <asp:Label ID="Lbl2" runat="server" CssClass="norm"> Show Names:</asp:Label>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="ChkNames" runat="server"></asp:CheckBox>
        &nbsp;<asp:Button ID="btnShow" Text="Go" runat="server" OnClick="btnShow_Click">
        </asp:Button>
    </div>
    <!--End:Filters-->
    <br />
    <!--Start:Grid-->
    <div>
        <asp:Label ID="lblBeginning" runat="server" CssClass="head2">&nbsp;&nbsp;Week:</asp:Label>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="datepicker" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" CssClass="norm"
            OnTextChanged="datepicker_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
     <br />
    </div>
    <asp:DataGrid ID="dgData" runat="server" CssClass="DG" Width="100%" CellPadding="4"
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" GridLines="Vertical" OnItemDataBound="dgData_ItemDataBound">
        <AlternatingItemStyle CssClass="Alternating"></AlternatingItemStyle>
        <ItemStyle CssClass="Item"></ItemStyle>
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateColumn>
                <HeaderStyle CssClass="head"></HeaderStyle>
                <ItemStyle CssClass="bdr"></ItemStyle>
            </asp:TemplateColumn>
        </Columns>
    </asp:DataGrid>
    <!--End:Grid-->
```

code behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {

                if (Session["Week"] != null)
                {
                    DateTime dDate = DateTime.Parse(Session["Week"].ToString());
                    datepicker.Text = Utils.GetFirstDateOfWeek(dDate, DayOfWeek.Monday).ToString("dd MMM yyyy");
                }
                else
                {
                    datepicker.Text = Utils.GetFirstDateOfWeek(DateTime.Now, DayOfWeek.Monday).ToString("dd MMM yyyy");
                    Session["Week"] = datepicker.Text.ToString();
                }

            }
            BindData(datepicker.Text, ChkDetails.Checked, ChkNames.Checked);

        }

        protected void datepicker_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BindData(datepicker.Text, ChkDetails.Checked, ChkNames.Checked);
            Session["Week"] = datepicker.Text.ToString();
        }
        protected void BindData(string sWkDate, Boolean bDetails, Boolean bNames)
        {
            DataSet ds = null;
            ds = ListGridDetails(sWkDate);

            //  .................
        }
        protected void dgData_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataGridItemEventArgs e)
        {

            if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem | e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item | e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.SelectedItem)
            {
                LinkButton lnk = default(LinkButton);
                lnk = new LinkButton();
                lnk.Text = "Amend";
                lnk.CommandName = "Amend";
                lnk.CommandArgument = id;
                lnk.Command += new CommandEventHandler(AmendButtonClick);
                e.Item.Cells[i].Controls.Add(lnk);

            }
        }
        public void AmendButtonClick(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
        {

            //.............

            this.mpeAmend.Show();

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

On postback `Page_Load` called as well and your binding logic invokes because it doesn't stands under `!Page.IsPostBack`. Try use this

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {

        if (Session["Week"] != null)
        {
            DateTime dDate = DateTime.Parse(Session["Week"].ToString());
            datepicker.Text = Utils.GetFirstDateOfWeek(dDate, DayOfWeek.Monday).ToString("dd MMM yyyy");
        }
        else
        {
            datepicker.Text = Utils.GetFirstDateOfWeek(DateTime.Now, DayOfWeek.Monday).ToString("dd MMM yyyy");
            Session["Week"] = datepicker.Text.ToString();
        }

        BindData(datepicker.Text, ChkDetails.Checked, ChkNames.Checked);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, when the filters are used it only binds once, but when the linkbutton is clicked (in the cells ) that opens the modal popup.  The datagrid has nothing in it and the amendbutton doesn't fire.